# Increase Speed of Rails View Generation When Multiple Tables Are Involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got these models

```
class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :players_to_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :players, through: :players_to_teams
  belongs_to :account
end
```

In my show view for `teams`, I show all the `players` on that `team`.  The edit link actually goes to edit the `players_to_teams` entry, so I had something like this:

```
  <% @team.players.each do |player| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= player.FirstName %></td>
    <td><%= player.LastName %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_players_to_team_path(player.players_to_teams.find_by_team_id(@team.id)) %></td>
  </tr>
```

where `@team` was defined as `Team.find(params[:id])`.  This was SUPER slow, and when looking at the dev logs, it was because the db was being hit numerous times for every player at the `edit_players_to_team_path` line (to find the player, then to find the player_to_team that matched the requirements, maybe more?).

So I switched it instead to use the `players_to team` record

```
<% @players_to_teams.each do |ptt| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ptt.player.FirstName %></td>
    <td><%= ptt.player.LastName %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_players_to_team_path(ptt) %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

where `@players_to_teams` is eqaul to `team.players_to_teams` in the controller.  This goes a lot faster, but still seems to be hitting the db for every row in my view.

I'm guessing `Team.find(params[:id])` doesn't return the `players` or `players_to_teams` records that are associated with that `team`.  Is there a way I can include those associations so that a call to `Team.find(params[:id])` returns an object with references to both the `player` and `player_to_teams` associated records, so the db only gets hit once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving the @player_to_teams records, eager load the players in that query using `.include(:player)` (actual syntax may vary depending on the query you are using).  That way the app will make 1 call to the database to get the ptt records and possibly one more call to get all the players.  This will avoid having to lookup the player for each ptt iteration in the view. Here's a link that demonstrates - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations